# iOS - What does the following LAContext error logs on iOS mean?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, lacontext

I keep getting the following log in my console.

`[Client,LAContext] LAContext[5174:1692] will keep returning Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-10 "Invalidated due to exceeded number of allocated contexts." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalidated due to exceeded number of allocated contexts.} from now on.`

Can any one help with this? What generates this?

Comment: Hi AjinkyaSharma ... have you found any solution to this ... am facing the same issue when navigating to another screen in SwiftUI and my application get freez .. Its a strange behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are creating multiple `LAContext` objects, from my own tests on 12 Pro Sim this error occurs after you have 65 `LAContext` that haven't been invalidated.

`LAContext` should automatically be invalidated when it is released.  Perhaps you are instantiating it in a ViewController and your ViewController has a retain cycle preventing the `LAContext` being released?

You can manually invalidate `LAContext` by calling `invalidate()` on the instance.